# Ionization enthalpy for group 13 elements

Tags: periodic-trends, ionization-energy, boron-family

> The ionization enthalpy for elements along a group generally reduces.
> But there is an exception for group 13 elements and the order is not
> uniform.
>
> The order is:
> **B>Tl>Ga>Al>In**

According to my textbook, Xam idea Class 11 Chemistry Book for CBS, on page 153, the reason for this is the weak screening effect of electrons in d and f orbitals.
What does this mean?

*The following is an excerpt from my textbook:*

> *The ionization enthalpy values as expected
> from the general trends do not decrease
> smoothly down the group. The decrease from
> B to Al is associated with an increase in size. The
> observed discontinuity in the ionization
> enthalpy values between Al and Ga, and
> between In and Tl are due to the inability of d- and
> f-electrons,which have a low screening effect, to
> compensate for the increase in nuclear charge.*

[Source](http://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/kech204.pdf)

Comment: Except for boron, the differences between the ionization enthalpies in G13 seem quite small, no?